# WebGL color mix calculation

Tags: graphics, colors, webgl, color-scheme

What is **WebGL** color mix calculation algorithm? I need to draw quadrangle with 4-way gradient color fill and I decided to do it with 3-way gradient triangles (like [this](http://learningwebgl.com/blog/?p=134)), calculating the center of quadrangle and using such point for 4 triangles to get the best result of gradient smoothness. To do it right, I need to calculate the color of the center of quadrangle by **same way as WebGL calculates color mix for 3-way gradient fill**. What is the formular for such calculation?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

WebGL uses linear interpolation for vertex attributes. The formula for interpolating a value across a square given samples at the four corners is simply linear interpolation applied twice. In GLSL,

```
mix(mix(color00, color01, y), mix(color10, color11, y), x)
```

If you are interested in the center point in particular, this is just

```
0.25 * (color00 + color01 + color10 + color11)
```

---

However, if your goal is to interpolate the four colors smoothly across a square, in a WebGL application, then you don't actually need to perform this calculation yourself, and you don't need to use four triangles!

1. Create a 2×2 texture with your four colors.
2. Set its `TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER` to `LINEAR`.
3. Draw your square with that texture applied in the usual fashion, but with texture coordinates ranging from `0.25` to `0.75`.

This performs the same interpolation you're looking for, but using built-in facilities. If you wanted, you could also skip using a texture, but still have “texture” coordinates, and use the `mix` formula above to map the coordinates to your four colors.

The reason this works is that texture coordinates, *unlike* arbitrary colors, are such that linearly interpolating between 3 points gives you non-degenerate results which you can then use to lookup the color taking into consideration all 4 color values.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I am a newbie in WebGL. Can you please clarify for me what you mean by `color00`, `color01`, `color10`, `color11`,...? Some example would be very helpfull. Thanks!

Comment: Those are just vector variables containing your four colors, named for the coordinates of four corners, for the sake of my example. How you get them is up to you. If you use the texture approach I suggested instead, there are no such variables, anyway.

Comment: Would your texture approach work for **ANY** quadrangle? Not just convex, but also concave quadrangles? Thanks.

Comment: If I've thought it through correctly, this only applies to squares. However — if you have a non-square quadrilateral, then you will need to be more specific about *what result you want* — there is no longer a single “correct” choice. If you wish to ask here further, then I suggest that you revise your question to be much more concrete: specify *what you are going to use this colored non-square for*, and *what properties you wish it to have to accomplish that*.